# My onTouch method is not doing what it is programmed to do

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, touch-event, ontouch

I am making a Android app. The objective is to make circles that when touched something happens.In more detail this app will display 2 types of circles either a red or a green one. The color of the circle is stored in the lastColor variable. The purpose of the color is so that when a user "touches" a red or green circle something happens. For example if a green circle is touched a point is added to there score, or if a red circle is clicked the activity is changed, but when either of the circles are clicked nothing happens. Here is the onTouch method

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int x = (int) event.getX();
   int y = (int) event.getY();
   if(isInsideCircle(x, y) ==  true){
      //Do your things here
       if(redColor == lastColor){
          Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
          v.getContext().startActivity(i);
       } else {
           addPoints++;
       }
   }else {

   }
   return true;
}
```

This part of the code is the thing that is not functioning properly. Here is the entire class below.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 0);

    private static final int w = 100;
    public static int lastColor = Color.BLACK;
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final int radius = 230;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static int redColor = Color.RED;
    public static int greenColor = Color.GREEN;
    int randomWidth = 0;
    int randomHeight = 0;
    public static int addPoints = 0;

    private final Runnable updateCircle = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? redColor : greenColor;
            paint.setColor(lastColor);
            invalidate();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        handler.post(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // your other stuff here
        if (random == null) {
            randomWidth = (int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth() - radius / 2)) + radius / 2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int) Math.abs((getHeight() - radius / 2 + radius / 2f))));
        }
        else {
            randomWidth = (int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth() - radius / 2)) + radius / 2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int) Math.abs((getHeight() - radius / 2 + radius / 2f))));
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidth, randomHeight + radius / 2f, radius, paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(150);
        canvas.drawText("Score: " + addPoints, 120, 300, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        if (isInsideCircle(x, y) == true) {
            //Do your things here
            if (redColor == lastColor) {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
            else {
                addPoints++;
            }
        }
        else {

        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isInsideCircle(int x, int y) {
        if ((((x - randomWidth) * (x - randomWidth)) + ((y - randomHeight) * (y - randomHeight))) < ((radius) * (radius)))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: *" when touched something happens."* like what? *"This part of the code is the thing that is not functioning properly"* how?

Comment: when a green or a red circle is "touched" it is suppose to do something. if its a red circle it will display another activity if its a green circle it will add a point, but of course nothing happens when i click anywhere

Comment: Is it crashing or simply doing nothing? Have you put logs and/or breakpoints to see what is/isn't getting called? As it stands, this is a pretty broad question with a lack of self-debugging which makes it difficult for others to solve.

Comment: not crashing just not doing anything when i "touch" or click something on the emulator

Comment: logs or breakpoints? logs as in logcat? there is no errors in logcat

Comment: If (randomWidth, randomHeight) is supposed to be the coordinate of your circle's center, you need to change your canvas.drawCircle line to be just canvas.drawCircle(randomWidth, randomHeight, radius, paint);

Comment: that makes sense i dont know why i had that there, but i removed and still nothing happend

Comment: You should be able to figure out what's going on using the debugger in Android Studio or Eclipse (whatever you're using).  Check out this article for a description of how to run in debug mode, breakpoint placement, etc. https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: @PaulTrueman I'm not talking about the logcat. I mean [setting log statements and breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html) to see which lines are/aren't being hit.

Comment: yeah none of that helped

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the onTouchEvent function. I tested the code and it fully works! Also, make sure to return false after addPoints++ to ensure only one point is added. Hopefully this works for you!

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    if (isInsideCircle(x, y)) {
        //Do your things here
        if (redColor == lastColor) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), null);
            getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
        else {
            addPoints++;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {

    }
    return true;
}
```